# Mootools Lightbox for a html div?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, mootools, lightbox

I'm wondering if anyone has ever come across a plug-in for mootools that will show a hidden div (with embedded video in it) as a light box, upon a click on a link.

What I wanted is somehow like how apple trailers site show the embedded quicktime player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) a try... It supports multiple frameworks (MooTools, jQuery etc.), multiple players (img, iframe, html) and a lot of other options.

You can also check [this matrix](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) to see an overview of popular Lightbox clones with their capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

[Clientcide](http://www.clientcide.com/wiki/cnet-libraries/07-ui/07-stickywin.modal) has one that might work. You could also try [Milkbox](http://reghellin.com/milkbox/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try moodalbox - not sure how it compares with milkbox, which I haven't used, but moodalbox should be able to do it: http://www.e-magine.ro/web-dev-and-design/36/moodalbox/